# Apache POI missing setDefaultRowStyle(row, style)?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Apache POI features a `XSSFSheet.setDefaultColumnStyle`, but no corresponding method to set a default row style. A similar sounding method is available through `XSSFSheet.getRow(row).setRowStyle(style)`, but it does not work as expected: where `setDefaultColumnStyle` applies to newly created cells in that column, `setRowStyle` only applies to cells left empty.

Is this a bug in Apache POI, or am I missing a method that works like `setDefaultColumnStyle` for rows ?